# Mule Server 3.6 > Anypoint Studio > Remote Deployment Error

Tags: java, maven, mule, esb, mule-studio

Need help on how to resolve this issues I am encountering when I try to deploy to a remote server:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T19:57:37+08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

[10:17:36] Running: mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mule globe.pgsia Application 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for javax.script:jruby-engine:jar:jdk14:1.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.ibm.icu:icu4j-normalizer_transliterator:jar:4.8.1.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.googlecode.sardine:sardine:jar:248 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1-osgi/activation-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/javax/activation/activation/1.1-osgi/activation-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/javax/activation/activation/1.1-osgi/activation-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1-osgi/activation-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.codehaus.org/javax/activation/activation/1.1-osgi/activation-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/activation/activation/1.1-osgi/activation-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/javax/activation/activation/1.1-osgi/activation-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1-osgi/activation-1.1-osgi.pom
[WARNING] The POM for javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar:1.1-osgi is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.codehaus.org/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1-osgi/dom4j-1.6.1-osgi.pom
[WARNING] The POM for dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-osgi is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 55.277 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-16T10:18:32+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/332M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project globe.pgsia: Could not resolve dependencies for project ph.codebridge:globe.pgsia:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.ibm.icu:icu4j-normalizer_transliterator:jar:4.8.1.1, com.googlecode.sardine:sardine:jar:248: Failure to find com.ibm.icu:icu4j-normalizer_transliterator:jar:4.8.1.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I am deploying to a Mule 3.6 Server EE Trial... I had tried to recreate the project using the CE runtime but encountered another issue before even deploying which on one of my Java source regarding an error on import of the following libraries:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.HttpClientUtils;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

Thanks in advance.

.ubuntux

Answer (score 0):

From your console maven couldn't find the pom file path for two jar files

1.geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar

2.dom4j:jar

try to install them to your local repository.

Comment: below link will give you the details on how to install using maven
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me on that... I encountered another issue where I am not able to find the following dependency packages:

    javax.script:jruby-engine:jar:jdk14:1.1
    com.ibm.icu:icu4j-normalizer_transliterator:jar:4.8.1.1
    com.googlecode.sardine:sardine:jar:248
    avax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi
    org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar:1.1-osgi
    dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-osgi

Codehaus repository is not available anymore. Any other source where I can download those packages?

Comment: looks like you are not able to connect OSGI repository.
Workaround for this is to de-mavenize  your project and remove the pom.xml and re-movenize,sothat you will get rid of jar import issue except two files  1.sardine-248.jar,2.icu4j-normalizer_transliterator:jar:4.8.1.1  these two jar's you need to install manually